# Magento 2 Add 35% price to product and 16% tax

Tags: magento2, price, shopping-cart-price-rules, tax

Is it possible to add 35% more price to products in one category, and also add 16% as tax?

I want products from certain categories to have 35% more prices in catalog price, and then add 16% of taxes in the summary cart.

I tried with price rules but it only applies for discounts.
And I don't know if it's possible to add 2 taxes, 1 for catalog price and the other for summary cart.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a Plugin.
app/code/Vendor/IncreasePrice/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product" shared="false">
        <plugin
                name="IncreasePrice_ProductPlugin"
                type="Vendor\IncreasePrice\Plugin\ProductPluginPrice"
                disabled="false"
                sortOrder="10" />
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/IncreasePrice/Plugin/ProductPluginPrice.php
In this Plugin I'm increasing the price of the products that has the attribute set "Incrementar_Precio". It increases 35% of the price of this products.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\IncreasePrice\Plugin;

use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface;

class ProductPluginPrice
{
    protected $_attributeRepository;

    public function __construct(
        AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository
    ) {
        $this->_attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
    }

    public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {

            $attributeSetRepository = $this->_attributeRepository->get($subject->getAttributeSetId());
        $attributeSetName = $attributeSetRepository->getAttributeSetName();

        if($attributeSetName == "Incrementar_Precio"){



            return $result+(($result*35)/100);
        } else {
            return $result;
        }

    }

}
```